# How to catch JSON sent to Web Browser with Python

Tags: python, json, browser, google-chrome-devtools

I'd like to work on JSON response which has been sent to Web Browser. Therefore I want to transfer (catch) it somehow into my python program. Unfortunatly I don't know how to do this. After research google I'm even more confused about it.

Could you help me with putting this json into my program and *also with understanding the problem*? Now, I don't even know where to start.

On the left ther is trade market and on the right there is json with described goods.

https://gyazo.com/1aabaf3380a3242afe097d2fdb450893

fragment of header:
[header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1Co7.png)

P.S. Sending requests directly to server is over my skill now:

> These HTTP requests contain a header called 'Signature' which in turn contains a hash of the request being sent. This is used to sign the request so that the server can verify it hasn't been tampered with and also to make it more difficult to manipulate the request
>
> ...
>
> Let’s pick up the gold from another building and investigate the request. We see that the only part that has been changed is some integer in requestData. It looks like this is the id of the building. Paste it into our request in Composer, changing the id there, and then click Execute. Oops, we got error response this time. There is another part of the payload which is different in different requests and we missed it – *some hash prepended to JSON object. Obviously, it is generated inside the app. We need to get the app file now, decompile and investigate it.*

https://ingweland.com/writing-the-bot-for-forge-of-empires-mmo-game/

So I'm looking for way to catch response (json) which already has been requested by web browser.

As suggested I try using `requests`. Below output:

```py
import requests

payload = [{"__class__":"ServerRequest","requestData":[],"requestClass":"TradeService",
           "requestMethod":"getTradeOffers","requestId":83}]
res = requests.request(method='GET', url='https://pl2.forgeofempires.com/game/json?h=NbqBNMcMW-etbf4__Qgmyfoc')

print(res.text)
```

output:

```
Your session expired etc...
```

Despite in web browser game is still open... therefore I try to find this json "somewhere in chrome" but I don't know how to do it...

`h=NbqBNMcMW-etbf4__Qgmyfoc` it changes with every new session.

https://gyazo.com/682900872674349eb7e947bf7dd6e892

I can manually copy it directly from Chrome DevTool so there must be a way to get it somewhere and import to python, I guess.

When I copy it as: `Copy as cURL (cmd)` I get:

```
curl 'https://pl2.forgeofempires.com/game/json?h=NbqBNMcMW-etbf4__Qgmyfoc' -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' -H 'origin: https://pl2.forgeofempires.com' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,es;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,it;q=0.4,ja;q=0.3,nl;q=0.2' -H 'signature: 3a4928cbdb' -H 'cookie: instanceId=vi6mg2xcd; metricsUvId=577d80f4-a276-4743-8e29-e1307b522b4e; cid=991675081; ig_conv_last_site=https://pl2.forgeofempires.com/game/index; _fbp=fb.1.1566745595369.850276070; sid=Ck6jBRlYqOTI6OjtX1upneo88-VD9vvJ2oYw5mKF' -H 'client-identification: version=1.159; requiredVersion=1.159; platform=bro; platformType=html5; platformVersion=web' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Mobile Safari/537.36' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://pl2.forgeofempires.com/game/index?' -H 'authority: pl2.forgeofempires.com' -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' --data-binary '[{"__class__":"ServerRequest","requestData":[],"requestClass":"TradeService","requestMethod":"getTradeOffers","requestId":83}]' --compressed
```

Comment: https://github.com/Nikolaj-K/json-scraper

Comment: What have you tried ? Looking at what you've shared you *should* be able to use [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) with the URL that you're seeing over at the browser console if it doesn't require any form of authentication.

Comment: I answered but then I saw your edit. Why you can't re-request the json?

Comment: https://pl2.forgeofempires.com/game/json?h=3Sl2AjcTzm5hjxHc945fbOT_
this is link to json. When I request it, the response is empty.
If I understand it properly there some authentification method (hash ?) which server requires

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. @Artur Have you managed to find a way around this?